# why -1 is falsy ? - for (

Tags: javascript, for-loop

The for loop bellow works as it was intended, but I just do not understand why.

```
for (var i = 10;i--;) { 
    console.log("i: " + i); 
}
```

console: >> 9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0

I googled for the **falsy values: 0 and -0 .. (what does -0 mean ?) But if 0 is considered to be falsy, why the for loop gets evaluated with it ?** Actually the  original code sample actually look like this:

```
for (var i = e.length; i--; )
    e[i].apply(this, [args || {}]);
```

It looks cool, but I just do not get why it works.

Comment: A hint: Compare to `for (var i = 10;--i;) { console.log("i: " + i); }`. (Preincrement vs Postincrement)

Comment: Regarding `0` and `-0`: These are indeed different values, because the sign is stored in a designated bit and is independent of the other bits which represent the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `for` condition in

```
for (var i = 10;i--;) { 
    console.log("i: " + i); 
}
```

the `i` is evaluated **before** being decreased (due to the post-decrement operator).  Hence it is 1 in the condition and 0 when you actually print it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just do not like shortcuts that makes readability more difficult. In this case if i-- was the third tag, "i" would get evaluated just at the end of the  for loop by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Roberto Reale explained the reason, but I think this problem can also be solved by using the 3 statements in the `for` loop:

```js
for (var i = 9; i >= 0; i--) { 
    console.log("i: " + i); 
}
```

It will display integers from `9` to `0`.